How to send a transaction to anchor program using @solana/web3.js
I want to send a transaction for anchor program using solana web3.js
please help me :(

@Jimii Yup I have a IDL from anchor program

@Jimii I developed anchor program, but I need to send a transaction using solana@web3.js, because I developed chrome extension but It's not working at anchor client :(

If you have the IDL, you can convert the anchor method into a regular transaction which you can send/sign using regular web3.js
let tx = program.anchorMethod.accountsStrict({
 // -- snip
})
.transaction();

sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx)

Or you can convert it to an ix using instruction and bundle it with other instructions before sending it.
This is how we do it at Soundwork. Here is the reference code

Thank you for your favor! Although it didn't work this way, Solved this problem for changing provider wallet to NodeWallet.
But I checked your way its worked thoe. Thank you very much :))

Also nice to your reference Soundwork
